# IF conditional check for odd/even behaves opposite

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

This code should return area and perimeter with the radio, that, does it, though will should addition the odd numbers when the radio is odd, but it does the opposite.

```
        //int radio;
        float radio, area, perimetro, PI = 3.1416f;
        string texto;
        //float constante = 3.1416f;


        Console.Write("Ingrese Radio del Circulo: ");
        texto = Console.ReadLine();
        radio = int.Parse(texto);

        area = PI * radio * radio;
        perimetro = 2 * PI * radio;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEl area del circulo es: " + area);
        Console.WriteLine("El Perimetro del circulo es: " + perimetro);


        if ((radio % 2) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nSuma Impares: " + (radio + area + perimetro));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nEl Radio es Par");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPresione Cualquier tecla para finalizar");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should change it to if ((radio % 2) != 0)
which odd number will fulfill if statement

Answer (score 1):

Odd number means `if ((radio % 2) == 1)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is here:

```
if ((radio % 2) == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nSuma Impares: " + (radio + area + perimetro));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nEl Radio es Par");
}
```

`(radio % 2) == 0` means it is a pair and you are looking for odd instead, so you should do this:

```
if ((radio % 2) != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nSuma Impares: " + (radio + area + perimetro));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nEl Radio es Par");
}
```